# Symfony and PostgreSQL — this error is driving me crazy

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, nginx, pdo

I have installed php 5.6.13, nginx, postgresql (using brew, on Mac OS)

I found in log:

```
PDOException: could not find driver at /project-folder//vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40
```

and thought what this is simple mistake in parameters.yml, but everything is OK in parameters and config.

Command `doctrine:schema:create` and `doctrine:fixtures:load` **working fine** with same settings!

So I checked php:

```
>> php -m

PDO
pdo_dblib
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
```

try clear cache: `console cache:clear`

remove and set up cache, logs folders with http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

But I can not login on the site and everytime have save error `PDOException: could not find driver`

I have no idea — how it can loading fixtures, but can not find PDO driver, when I try to login on the site.

I tried many time remove and install php56, php56-pdo-pgsql, nginx... Any idea...

---

## UPDATE

Problem solved after restart Mac OS.

Comment: You should know that PHP runs in "two different instances": one from command line and one through your web server (nginix). When you do php -m from cli, you're inspecting cli php's modules loaded. I can put one dollar on this answer: you haven't installed that module on php used by ws

Comment: Thank! So I don't know this magic. I tried to start/stop nginx and reload config (of course I checked it with 'phpinfo()'), postgres etc. but nothing to work. Problem solved with Windows-way — just reboot. 
I found the answer on one site what os must be restarted after removed/updated php. The irony is that I did not attach any importance to this :)

Comment: Thank you! Stuck with the same issue on Ubuntu. After reboot works fine! Unfortunately spent hour for debugging.